# How can I target the opacity of an icon within a button (without affecting the entire button)?

Tags: button, model-view-controller

I may not have described the issue accurately with the title, but it's easier to explain here:

I have a button that has an icon image contained within it.  I need to get rid of the grey box around that icon and keep the icon itself, along with the button functionality.  I assigned the button a second class called "nogray", and in my styling sheet I set opacity to 0.

However, this got rid of the entire button, along with the little orange trash bin icon, which I need to be visible.  Essentially, I need the button to function the same way, just with the orange icon and no grey box. In this screenie, you can see the buttons at the top of each bulletin note.  [image: buttons in the upper right of each note]

Here is the button code in the bulletin notes view:

```
 <button class ="remove-card nogray" id="@item.BulletinId" type="button"><i 
 class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
```

And here is the css for the button:

```
i.fa.fa-trash::before {
content: "\f1f8";


}
.remove-card.nogray {
opacity:0;
}
```

(i.fa.fa-trash::before  targets the trash icon, and .remove-card.nogray  targets the outer gray area.  However, I suspect that the latter is targetting the entire button because setting the opacity to 0 affects both gray area and icon.

How would I tweak the button code so that the opacity is 0 only for the grey, and not the icon?  I've tried changing the order of the code element by element, but a lot of it is guesswork because this is a team effort and I did not personally write the button code.  I'd also like to apologize in advance if this is an impossible question to answer; if there's some detail you need to know, please tell me and I will edit this to include it.

Thank you very much for any suggestions!

Comment: The weird part is I tried targeting both .remove-card.nogray as well as i.fa.fa-trash::before and set opacity to 0, within style sheet. But neither outcome led to the gray part disappearing; either the whole button disappears, or the trash icon disappears

Answer (score 0):

I realized I was targeting the wrong lines of code in my css.  There was an ActionLink that a teammate commented out, and I assigned the classes from that to my original button code and was able to target the button that way instead.